How To Mock Go Router
In Flutter I have a unit test where I am trying to test whether my code is correctly navigating to another page. I use mocktail for testing.
To start I created a mock router as follows:
class MockGoRouter extends Mock implements GoRouter {}

Then I created a router provider to provide the go router to my context:
class MockGoRouterProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  const MockGoRouterProvider({
    required this.goRouter,
    required this.child,
    super.key,
  });

  final MockGoRouter goRouter;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => InheritedGoRouter(
        goRouter: goRouter,
        child: child,
      );
}

And when pump my widget I do the following:
 MaterialApp(
  home: MockGoRouterProvider(
  goRouter: router ?? MockGoRouter(),
  child: widget,
),

Now finally to use this in my tests where I'm trying to test code that calls goRouter.replace I do:
final mockRouter = MockGoRouter();
when(() => mockRouter.replace(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {});

However, when this code runs I get the following error:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown running a test:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Object?>'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      MockGoRouter.replace (file:///...mock_router.dart:5:7)
#1      GoRouterHelper.replace (package:go_router/src/misc/extensions.dart:116:25)
#2      GetCodeViewController._updateValidationStatus (package:.....)
#3      GetCodeViewController.validateCode (package:....)
<asynchronous suspension>

Unfortunately I can't find a lot of resources on mocking go_router so any help is appreciated.

The steps you described seem correct but the error indicates that maybe you don't create the stub method response for router.replace at the right time.
Here's a full working example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class MockGoRouter extends Mock implements GoRouter {}

class MockGoRouterProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  const MockGoRouterProvider({
    required this.goRouter,
    required this.child,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final MockGoRouter goRouter;

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => InheritedGoRouter(
        goRouter: goRouter,
        child: child,
      );
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          GoRouter.of(context).replace('/home');
        },
        child: const Text('Go home'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  late MockGoRouter router;

  setUp(() {
    router = MockGoRouter();
    when(() => router.replace(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {});
  });

  test('Router test', () async {
    await router.replace('/home');
    verify(() => router.replace('/home')).called(1);
  });

  testWidgets('Widget test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: MockGoRouterProvider(
          goRouter: router,
          child: const LandingPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    await tester.tap(find.text('Go home'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    verify(() => router.replace('/home')).called(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(router);
  });
}


Thanks for your answer. I won't be able to look at this today, but will be able to test it Friday and give you your bounty then if it works

Interestingly, your first test is passing, but my modified test which calls replace inside the actual code is still throwing that same error

Can you update the question with this modified test that is throwing the same error?
